# How to convert yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: php, date, format

In PHP I am using date convertion for europedate function like

```
strtotime($rowadd['your date']);
```

but the 0000/00/00 date showing same string it will be

showing `default(ex:01/01/1970).`

I need exact zero date will be display as zero date.
any other PHP function are there? for convert europe date format

Comment: Google Translate still needs some refinement, seemingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($yourtimestring));
```

for 0 you can just manually replace it with a conditional.